Quarkus RestClient DNS failover on multiple A type IP addresses?
I am using Quarkus RestClient and I encountered some problems.
I have an URL, which is internally resolved to 4 different IP addresses (data and IP addresses are pseudonymized in this example):
[user@server]$ dig service.example.com

;; ANSWER SECTION:
service.example.com.    740 IN  CNAME   service-example-com.some-internal-resolution.com.
service-example-com.some-internal-resolution.com. 290 IN A  300.300.351.76
service-example-com.some-internal-resolution.com. 290 IN A  300.300.350.1
service-example-com.some-internal-resolution.com. 290 IN A  300.300.349.76
service-example-com.some-internal-resolution.com. 290 IN A  300.300.348.1

It seems to me that the Quarkus RestClient only fetches the first IP address, because the problem is, when this first IP address is not reachable, I get a connection timeout, although the other ones are reachable, so I think that this is a problem with the RestClient?
Is there a way to bypass this behaviour so the RestClient tries the other IP addresses as well if the first one is not reachable?

That's the expected behavior. To do what you want, you need to use stork (the service discovery framework of Quarkus) - https://smallrye.io/smallrye-stork/1.3.1/service-discovery/dns/
And then:
quarkus.stork.my-service.service-discovery.type=dns

and your rest client would use the stork://my-service URL.

Looks promising. Thanks for the tip, I will try that out.

This framwork does not seem to solve my problem. There does not seem to be some mechanism to redirect a request to another A type IP. It seems that it can only fetch information about available services form a dns server (in case of dns setting), so in the end I still have the same problem as before. So I need to find another solution.

Stork will resolve the list of A records and then implement a round robin among them (or another selection strategy, round robin is the default one)

I think I found a solution now: See https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-stork/discussions/829
